# dxe:listbox not checking items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, devexpress

Im creating a listbox (devexpress control) like this

```
 <dxe:ListBoxEdit x:Name="lstBoxFeatures" DisplayMember="Description" ValueMember="FeatureId" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Features, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Height="320"                                     
                                 EditValue="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedFeatures, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                 >
                    <dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                        <dxe:CheckedListBoxEditStyleSettings  />    
                    </dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>                                                  
                </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
```

I have the view, i fill it like this
I filling the values like this (are using a list of features)

```
_CustomerLicense.Features = GetFeatureList(SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);
_CustomerLicense.SelectedFeatures =_CustomerLicense.Features.Where(x => FeaturesIds.Contains(x.FeatureId)).ToList();
```

The process where i get ths list of features

```
   private List<Feature> GetFeatureList(Project.Common.Domain.ProductEnum ProductID )
    {
        var Res = new List<Feature>();
        var Features = new LicenseService().GetFeatures(ProductID);
        Features.ForEach((x)=> {
            Res.Add(new Feature(x));
        });
        return Res;
    }
```

The view i have this way

```
 public List<Feature> Features
    {
        get { return _Features;}
        set
        {
            _Features = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Features");
        }
    }     

    public List<Feature> SelectedFeatures
    {
        get { return _SelectedFeatures; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedFeatures = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedFeatures");
        }
    }
```

When i run the app it sets the values, the listbox is populated with all the reatures in the list but the selected features are not checked.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring `SelectedFeatures` as a List of Objects (you'll need to change `_SelectedFeatures` too):

```
public List<object> SelectedFeatures
{
    get { return _SelectedFeatures; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedFeatures = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedFeatures");
    }
}
```

and change this line:

```
_CustomerLicense.SelectedFeatures =_CustomerLicense.Features.Where(x => FeaturesIds.Contains(x.FeatureId)).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur
It worked like you said, i changed SelectedFeatures as objects and it worked.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedFeatures` collection should contain a subset of the `Feature` instances that are in the `Features` collection. Try this:

```
var features = GetFeatureList(SelectedLicense.Product.ProductId);
_CustomerLicense.Features = features;

var selectedFeatureIds = _CustomerLicense.Features.Where(x => FeaturesIds.Contains(x.FeatureId)).Select(x => x.FeatureId).ToList();
_CustomerLicense.SelectedFeatures = features.Where(x => selectedFeatureIds.Contains(x.FeatureId)).ToList();
```